# Get OS system and relative path to a folder in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I write my test on my local Windows, and I create webdriver like this:

```
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("browser")
public void setUp(String browser) throws Exception {
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.out.println("Chrome test starting ...");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver_win.exe");
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }        
    else {
        throw new Exception("Browser is not supported");
    }
```

For the setProperty, I use a hard path to Chrome Driver, but I would like change the path to relative by checking the OS to use appropriate driver for Windows and Mac. Can someone give me a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using config property file you can get both browser type and chrome driver location.

you can create one folder in your work space with the name **Drivers** and paste your chrome driver

Below is config.properties file

```
browserType=Chrome
ChromeDriver = Drivers/chromedriver.exe
```

Below is the code to run chrome driver on different operating systems

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
public String currentBrowser;
if(CONFIG.getProperty("browserType").contains(","))
{
  data=currentBrowser;
}
if (os.contains("Windows")) 
{     
    else if (data.equals("Chrome")) {
    APP_LOGS.debug("Chrome Browser Opening Method Start");
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    // To Accept SSL certificate
    capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            CONFIG.getProperty("ChromeDriver"));
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    long 
    implicitWaitTime=Long.parseLong(CONFIG.getProperty("implicitwait"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitWaitTime, 
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting `chromedriver` in `src`? Your `jar` will be needing that folders while running.

Source Code and the Binary files should **not** be put together in production environment.

Create a `libs` folder and put all types of `chromedrivers` in it. With slight change in name.

```
chromedriver_mac
chromedriver_win
chromedriver_linux
```

**Code**

```
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("browser")
public void setUp(String browser) throws Exception {
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.out.println("Chrome test starting ...");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", getChromeDriverPath());
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }        
    else {
        throw new Exception("Browser is not supported");
    }
}
public static String getChromeDriverPath() {
      String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");

        if (OS.contains("Window")) {
            return "libs/chromedriver_win"
        } else if (OS.contains("Mac")) {
            return "libs/chromedriver_mac"
        } else {
            return "libs/chromedriver_linux"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work,

```
if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("CHROME"))
{
  log.info("Executing Operating System = "+System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase());
  String osname =System.getProperty("os.name");
  if(osname.toLowerCase().contains("windows")) System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe" );
  else if(osname.toLowerCase().contains("linux"))
  {
    String filepathtoset = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",filepathtoset );
  } 
  else System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/test/resources/chromedrivermac");
```